# Fill an ArrayList with object from response.body

Tags: java, android, arraylist, request, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to get list of data from api. I want to save the data which I get in body.response to arrayList. I can do that and I get the items from new arrayList, but it seems that the new list are not saved. When I try to use it outside of method onResponse, I get an error

> Unable to start activity... IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0, Size 0

The interface

```
 public interface ServerApi {
        @Headers("Accept: application/json")
        @GET("cities")
        Call<ArrayList<City>> getCities();
    }
```

The activity

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://url")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ServerApi serverApi = retrofit.create(ServerApi.class);

    ArrayList<City> cityList = new ArrayList<City>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parkings);

        final TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        final Call<ArrayList<City>> cities = serverApi.getCities();

        cities.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<City>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<City>> call, Response<ArrayList<City>> response) {
                for(int i=0; i<response.body().size(); i++){
                    City ct = new City(response.body().get(i).getId(), response.body().get(i).getName());
                    cityList.add(ct);
                    tv1.setText(cityList.get(i).getName());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<City>> call, Throwable t) {
                tv1.setText("failure " + t);
            }
        });

      TextView c1 = findViewById(R.id.c1);
      c1.setText(cityList.get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

The string `tv1.setText(cityList.get(i).getName());` inside the method onResponse works well. But when I write it out of the method, the aplication fall

Comment: I am not 100% sure but  I think enqueue is run on a background thread. By the time you wrote the c1.setText the cityList is empty. That is the first thing I would check.

Comment: Firstly, enqueue runs asynchronously. cityList has no item when you try to access cityList.get(0)

Comment: You have to move your arraylist dependent code in a separate method and call it after receiving the response. As mentioned in the above comment, your list is empty when you are calling methods on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it can be seen you run your code in a background thread and a few lines below you try to update your textview on the UI thread. 
The background operation will take some time, therefore, by the time you try to update the TextView the cityList is empty. 
Consider reading a bit more here: [Consuming apis with retrofit](https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit)